# populate html select group using external json

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

i have an external json file that looks like this:

```
{
   "columns": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
   ],
   "rows": [
   { "1": "abc",
     "2": "def",
   },
   { "1": "ghi",
     "2": "jkl"
   }
  ]
 }
```

and an html file that looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control formSelect" name="{{form_select}}" multiple="multiple" required>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>
```

how do i get the values of "1"? and how do i populate an html select group with the values as select options?

i tried to log the contents of the json file but it's not logging.
here's my code:

```
function addSiteOptions()
{
var contents = fs.readFileSync("api_response_sample", 'utf8');
var jsonArray = JSON.parse(contents);
var options = [];
for(var x = 0; x < 2; x++)
{
   for(var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++)
   {
       options.push(jsonArray[1].rows.Site);
   }
}

return console.log("OPTIONS ARE" + options);

}
```

Comment: First of all, what is .hbs? Additionally, please post your attempts.

Comment: @Sydnie Check the documentation regarding [iterators](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#iterators).  Also, "not working" isn't an error code or error; please describe in more detail the problem.

Comment: @Sydnie Also, if you really are using handlebars.js, properly tag your question please.

Comment: sorry guys, edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your json is invalid. `"2": "def",` that comma should not be there.

```
{
    "columns": [ "A", "B", "C"],
    "rows": [
        { "1": "abc", "2": "def" },
        { "1": "ghi", "2": "jkl" }
    ]
}
```

After that, it is quite straightforward. Load the json file 
in your application, parse it and extract desired properties (in your case `1`).

Here is a minimal example of the application code.

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // parse json file
  const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8'));
  // extract desired properties
  const options = data.rows.reduce((acc, obj) => acc.concat(obj['1']), []);

  // send extracted options to your view
  res.render('index', { options });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

And in your view file (`index.hbs`), iterate through obtained `options` array to create `<option>` elements.

```
<select>
  {{#each options }}
    <option>{{ this }}</option>
  {{/each }}
</select>
```

NOTE: `hbs` is used in this answer, because the original question was about it.